# How to Resolve this Out of Memory Issue for a Small Variable in Matlab?

Tags: windows, matlab, out-of-memory

I am running a 32-bit version of Matlab R2013a on my computer (4GB RAM, and 32-bit Windows 7).
I have dataset (~ 60 MB) and I want to read it using

```
ds = dataset('File', myFile, 'Delimiter', ',');
```

And each time I face `Out of Memory` error. Theoretically, I should be able to use 2GB of RAM, so there should be no problem reading such small files.
Here is what I got when typed `memory`

```
Maximum possible array:     36 MB (3.775e+07 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:    421 MB (4.414e+08 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:    474 MB (4.969e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   3317 MB (3.478e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.
```

I followed every instructions I found (this is not a new issue), but for my case it seems rather weird, because I cannot run a simple program now.

System: Windows 7 32 bit
Matlab: R2013a
RAM: 4 GB

Comment: Try to step through `dataset()` in debug mode and see when that happens. It's hard to say what is causing the problem.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your task manager memory usage to confirm?

Comment: Possible related http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388

Answer (score 2):

Clearly your issue is right here.

```
Maximum possible array:     36 MB (3.775e+07 bytes) *
```

You are either using a lot of memory in your system and/or you have a very low swap space.

Comment: I removed my request for clarification in my answer and have posted in the question's comments. The content should still be correct.